# How to deal with 102 response in LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, http, lwp, lwp-useragent

I am sometimes getting 102 response from a web server. This response indicates that the server is processing the request but is not the final response for it  (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#1xx_Informational). The request(>) response (<) sequence might look like this:

> `>`GET some_url
>
> `<`HTTP/1.1 102 Processing
>
> `<`HTTP/1.1 102 Processing
>
> `<`HTTP/1.1 102 Processing
>
> `<`HTTP/1.1 200 OK

The server can be considered reliable in the sense that the final response is ultimately sent.

Using LWP::UserAgent (6.02) I can recognise that I've received a 102 using HTTP::Status::is_info() but what I then need to do is consume at least one and maybe more subsequent responses for the original request and I can't see  a way to do that once I have the response.

I thought I might be able to do it with a handler ([http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#Handlers](http://metacpan.org/pod/LWP%3a%3aUserAgent#Handlers)) which I use successfully elsewhere, but I can't find a way to force continuing to listen.

I've also looked for a way to turn on "102 awareness" within LWP and just have the library take care of listening for the final response which it then returns, but I can't see that either.

Tell me I'm missing something obvious, please.